# jquery not visible after dynamically adding it in script element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that dynamically loads jQuery, by inserting it in `<head>` element:

```
 // pseudo code

 headElelement.insertBefore(script, firstChild);
```

However, immediately after that call, I start to use jQuery, but at that moment it is undefined. How is that possible ?

Comment: if the code your running after you insert jquery after inside a `$(function () {});` block?

Comment: I just run this kind of code while (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
               
            } which runs forever

Comment: Please post the relevant code, otherwise it's just guesswork: what do you mean with the pseudo code, do you really load jquery in the HTML itself like `<head><script src="..."></script>...</head>`? Where do you try to use it, you say " immediately after that call", so in the head?

Answer (score 0):

That's because jQuery is not fully loaded yet. You may need to execute your jQuery code only after jQuery has been loaded by attaching an event handler to the `onload` event of your dynamically created script element as shown below.

```
script.onload = function() {
    // Put your jQuery code here.
    console.log(jQuery);
};
```

Cross-Browser solution for supporting older browsers like IE8 and below:

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.type === "load" || (/loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState))) {
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        // Put your jQuery code here.
        console.log(jQuery);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would post your relevant code it would be easier ;-) but anyways, this is one possible way of doing it:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_js/your_js_code.js"></script>
  ...
</head>...
```

and in the file your_js_code.js you'll have:

```
... /* All your modules and functions here */

/* DOM loading ready */
$(document).ready(function () {
  call_your_methods_here();
});
```

By the way, it is usually better to load your JS files at the very end of the `<body>` in the HTML, that way your HTML starts displaying first and the user "sees" your page faster, while the JS code is still loading.